# Retrieving many to many relationship data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have some problem using Entity Framework with a many-to-many relationship:

I have a `Reservation` class with `Membership` as a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Membership { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I retrieve `MembershipID` from membersip form foreach loop that I selected from reservation:

```
reservations = reservationRepo.Reservations.Where(r => 
    r.StartDatetime >= requestDate && r.EndDatetime <= endDate
    && r.Branch.BranchID == branchId).AsEnumerable();

foreach (var reservation in reservations)
{
    reservationList.Add(new ReservationModel
    {
        ReservationID = reservation.ReservationID,
        StartDatetime = reservation.StartDatetime,
        EndDatetime = reservation.EndDatetime,
        MembershipID = reservation.Membership????
    });
}
```

If I just return `reservations` I got :

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model says: *there is a collection of Memberships connected to that Reservation* and looks like you're trying to get just one of them. Are you sure that's what you need?

You can get list of `MembershipID`:

```
reservations = reservationRepo.Reservations.Include("Membership").Where(r => 
    r.StartDatetime >= requestDate && r.EndDatetime <= endDate
    && r.Branch.BranchID == branchId).AsEnumerable();

foreach (var reservation in reservations)
{
    reservationList.Add(new ReservationModel
    {
        ReservationID = reservation.ReservationID,
        StartDatetime = reservation.StartDatetime,
        EndDatetime = reservation.EndDatetime,
        MembershipIDs = reservation.Membership.Select(m => m.MembershipID).ToList()
    });
}
```

I've added `Include` call to your query, to eagerly load `Membership` content. Otherwise you'd get a lot of unnecessary DB calls within `foreach` loop because of lazy loading.

You should also probably make the projection part of your EF query, to fetch data from necessary columns only. That should decrease number of data flying between database and you application.

Comment: I have tried this method, I got this error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: This error is not connected to the query. It's problem with context being passed around.

Comment: Any other method? Trying to look for other way to solve this.